# Multiple executors on same worker fail in Spark standalone cluster (python scripts)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run a spark application on one worker with multiple executors.
My setup is of two machines:

- machine A is the client which will run the spark-submit command
- machine B (8 cores and 60gb ram) will run both the spark standalone master and one worker

When I submit the spark application (a python script) with spark.executor.cores set to 8. The application completes successfully while running on one executor. However; if I set the spark.executor.cores to 4, the spark worker will try to run the application with two executors, but the job will fail.

By inspecting the executors' stderr from the ui, I found that one executor runs normally while the other fails to receive the python script from the spark master.

The failing spark executor exception:

```
17/06/04 09:47:34 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream '/files/script.py' was not found.
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:222)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:120)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Note that I am using Spark 2.2